Google Sheets query formula partially working
I am making a sheet to pull data from a separate sheet based on user input. I have two named ranges to pull this data from based on a cells value. The front half of the formula works, but the back half returns an error of Col7 not found. I am sure I am missing something in plain sight. If there is an easier way to get the results I am after, I would appreciate the tip.
I have made a sample query range, to verify that the named range is working. The IFERROR statement has been removed from the back half of the formula so I could see the actual error. User input sheet Data tables sheet

Data4x10 does not start from column A (or B), so you can't use Col7 because there is no such column in Data4x10
try:
={"Price"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="",,
 IF(A2:A="4'x8'",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B, QUERY(
 IMPORTRANGE("17lswFD_i79JMAUAN5qgvKZnIjXMJCANoQjWPZpgCkSA", "Plate & Sheet!Data4x8"), "SELECT Col1, Col3 WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL", 0),2, FALSE)*D2:D,"N/A"), VLOOKUP(B2:B,QUERY(
 IMPORTRANGE("17lswFD_i79JMAUAN5qgvKZnIjXMJCANoQjWPZpgCkSA", "Plate & Sheet!Data4x10"),"SELECT Col1, Col3 WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL", 0),2, FALSE)*D2:D)))}



Thank you for explaining what I missed. Works perfectly.


You may try this in Cell_C1:
=vstack("Price",
 map(A2:A,B2:B,D2:D,lambda(a,b,d,if(or(a="",b=""),,iferror(round(vlookup(b,importrange("17lswFD_i79JMAUAN5qgvKZnIjXMJCANoQjWPZpgCkSA", "Plate & Sheet!Data"&substitute(a,"'",)),3,)*d,3),"--")))))


Thank you for the formula. I see I need to spend more time trying to use lambda.

Used this approach since your current formula seems to be rounding values differently for some reason. For example the price for Sheet 4x8 with size 10 ga is 0.026. When multiplied by quantity 2 its going to be 0.052; however your formula has it at 0.06

I wonder if that would be due to having the price columns set to round to two decimal places and the importrange pulls the rounded value and not the actual.

importrange by default does not round values. Once imported, the look can be changed to round 2 decimal spots but if you click on the actual cell, still should see the complete decimal values.

My data tables do have the cells/columns rounded. It looks like if I change the rounding, the importrange shows only what is displayed after the rounding and not the full decimal value.

Just try this part separately and then click on those price cells to see the full value =importrange("17lswFD_i79JMAUAN5qgvKZnIjXMJCANoQjWPZpgCkSA", "Plate & Sheet!Data4x8")
